# How can i remove junk values and load multiple .csv files(different Schema) into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i have many .csv files which are stored into gcs and i want to load data from.csv to BigQuery using below commands:

bq load 'datasate.table' gs://path.csv json_schema

i have tried but giving errors, same error is giving for many file.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lrze.png)

how can i remove unwanted values from .csv files before importing into table.

Suggest me to load file in easiest way

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what do you want to do with this junk rows. If you look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table), you have several options

- **Number of errors allowed**. By default, it's set to 0 and that why the load job fails at the first line. If you know the total number of rom, set this value to the Number of errors allowed and all the errors will be ignored in the Load Job
- **Ignore unknown values**. If your errors are made because some line contains more column as defined in the schema, this option keep the line in error and only the known column, the others are ignore
- **Allow jagged rows**. If your errors are made by too short line (and it is in your message) and you still want to keep the first columns (because the last ones are optional and/or not relevant), you can check this option

For more advanced and specific filters, you have to perform pre or post processing. If it's the case, let me know to add this part to my answer.